# Can a subprocess call (to blender) return a variable to the calling function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, blender

I have a python function which calls blender in the subprocess as shown below. The blender in turn runs a python script which creates the variable. I want to return this variable back to the original python function which invoked the subprocess. How would i do this?

```
#blender_sript.py
import bpy
import numpy as np

#create variable
return np.array([1,2,3])
```

```
import subprocess
res = subprocess.run(["blender", "-b", "-P", "blender_script.py"])
```

I would like to capture the returned numpy variable using the "res" variable

Comment: Processes can only output raw bytes over STDOUT. Pickle or other tools may help you encode the data for transfer then decode it again on the receiving end

Comment: @mousetail Could you show a very basic example of how to use pickle for this